# Store data to $localStorage.$default in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to store data in $localStorage Please help me
below is my code in angularjs

```
 $http.get(token_url+"jewellery/quick_keys/get_layout_data/"+edit_layout_id).success(function(result){ /* token url is to provide path to get layout list as per id*/
           console.log(result); /*result is in the form of jeson encode*/
    });
```

In console I get data as

```
new_layout [Object { _id=13952057,  name="Default 1",  page=[5],  more...}, Object { _id=55531173,  name="Default 2",  page=[3],  more...}, Object { _id=53907588,  name="Default 3",  page=[3],  more...}, Object { _id=6117442,  name="Default 4",  page=[3],  more...}]
```

i want to store this data to $localstorage.$default as in format as

```
new_layout: [{
              _id : 13952057,
              name:  'Default 1',
              page:  [{
                         pageID : 1,
                         product : [ name: 'Lee' }]
                      }],
              image: '<img src = "'+token_url+'images/grp1_setting_icon.png" >',
              Width: 25
           }]
      [{
              _id : 55531173,
              name:  'Default 2',
              page:  [{
                         pageID : 2,
                         product : [ name: 'Jo' }]
                      }],
              image: '<img src = "'+token_url+'images/grp1_setting_icon.png" >',
              Width: 25
           }]
```

Comment: why not to transfer data from server to client in JSON format and simply use `localStorage.setItem('new_layout', JSON.stringify(data))` on client?

Answer (score 0):

For local storage there is a module for that look at below url:

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

and other link for HTML5 local storage and angularJs

http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/html5-local-storage-angular-js

Also, You can use ngstorage:

ngStorage contains two services: $localStorage and $sessionStorage.

```
angular.module('app', [
   'ngStorage'
]).controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage,
    $sessionStorage
){});
```

You can see the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview&utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)
. Hope this helps.